# How to put the window in the top left corner with PyQt?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, qgis

I'm trying to put my window in the top left corner by runing the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.topLeft()
        self.show()

    def topLeft()(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        topLeftPoint = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry().topLeft()
        frameGm.moveTopLeft(topLeftPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But doing so, I get a gap between my window and the left-side of the screen like this :

[image]

Do you know where it comes from and how to prevent it?

Comment: Be more careful with examples, and ensure that they are always *both* [minimal *and* reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): QWidget is a class of QtWidgets in PyQt5 (not QtGui), and there's an unnecessary `()` in the declaration of `topLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when a window is shown the first time on the screen, some things (lots, actually) happen between `show()` and the moment where the window is *actually* mapped on the screen.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to delay the movement by some amount of time (usually, on "cycle" of the event loop is enough). Using a single shot QTimer with 1 timeout is normally fine.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(640, 480)
        QTimer.singleShot(1, self.topLeft)
        self.show()

    def topLeft(self):
        # no need to move the point of the geometry rect if you're going to use
        # the reference top left only
        topLeftPoint = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry().topLeft()
        self.move(topLeftPoint)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried to do so but still got the same issue. In fact these code lines are part of a function that resize the window when put on the edges of the screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518997/drag-window-to-the-edge-to-resize if you could have a lokk on it, you wll be of a great help! :)

Comment: What happens if you try to increase the timeout (for example, 1000, which is 1 second)?